# Contact Builder conceptual approach

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, contactbuilder, data-model

I am designing a data model for Contact Builder that will be connected to a Data warehouse, Service Cloud, mobile apps and many other systems. The main challenges I am facing are :

- Reducing the volume of Data and redundancy
- Designing a flexible data model for future integrations with other systems
- Respecting the standard use of Contact Builder and Journey Builder
- Building a flexible integration with Mobile Push SDK and mobile apps

In order to achieve these requirements, I need to understand how Contact Builder was designed in order to use it at best.

- Is Contact Builder based on a Star Schema ? Populations being the fact-tables and Attribute Groups/Sets being the dimension-tables ?

I am open to any kind of documentation or concepts that can help me shape this data model and please feel free to ask me questions in order to have better insights.